# Share Post From Facebook FanPage?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

Created a facebook application and a fan page tab which is rendering my site.

How can I create and share a post on User's wall using facebook API.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You're not clear at all!! What exactly you want to do mention that.

Comment: @Sahil Please Read my question carefully I am little bit confused

Comment: You're confused because your concepts are not clear. You cannot create an app which works as page.. and its unclear what are you trying to say regarding this sharing thing. Sorry but I think nobody here is willing to understand this question

Comment: @sahil I have updated my question please see it and try to give me answer.

Comment: You just want to publish a post on user's wall from the app? right? Are you using any sdk? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes you are right. I am using online javascript SDK.I tried lot of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use [`/me/feed`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/)-

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
{
    FB.init({
        appId      : '{app-id}',
        status     : true,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true 
    });

    FB.login(function(response){
        if (response.authResponse) {
            Share(); 
        } else {
            // The person cancelled the login dialog
        }
    },{scope: 'publish_actions'});

};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

function Share(){
   FB.api(
      "/me/feed",
      "POST",
      {
          "object": {
              "message": "This is a test message",
              "link": "{link}",
              "description": "{description}"
          }
      },
      function (response) {
         if (response && !response.error) {
            // success
         } 
      }
   );
}
```

Permissions required: `publish_actions`

Comment: m use javascript SDK.code: <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '{your-app-id}',
          status     : true,
          xfbml      : true
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script> How to share with it

Comment: You are asking lot of questions here, you are very weak with the basics of facebook API! you should have followed official docs

Comment: your answer really helpful me . How can I pass parameter in link?

Comment: I want to pass particular page id after https://www.facebook.com/appname/appid so while user click on this linkwith parameter I am check if page id=x then run my logic 1 otherwise logic 2.

Comment: That depends on you, you can use `?page_id=` and then use `$_GET`

Comment: When I pass link = "https://www.facebook.com/appname/app_id?page_id=5" its successfully post on fb wall but while click on this shared post its open ="https://www.facebook.com/appname?sk=appid&app_data" here How can I get my passed pageid?

Comment: Its not possible. See: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?%20app_id=145634995501895%20&display=popup&caption=An%20example%20caption%20&link=https://www.facebook.com/appname/app_id?page_id=5&redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer  If you share this and open the link it will show: https://www.facebook.com/App.Name/app_id?page_id=5

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50596/discussion-between-chirag-and-sahil-mittal)

Comment: Thanks for your replay . But My question is how can we get this page_id in iframe page means page tab url.